# Рыба рыбою сыта, а человек человеком

Tags: семантика

Что имеется в виду в старой поговорке "Рыба рыбою сыта, а человек человеком"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Странноватая заложенной в ней большой долей идеалистичности пословица из серии: человек человеку — друг, товарищ, брат. Отчасти так бывает, и это ценно. Но не этим сыт и не этим жив человек.

Comment: Спасибо, shampar!